# object.style.hasOwnProperty('MozTransform') returns false?

Tags: javascript, firefox

When using "hasOwnProperty" to check for the existence of a style property, Firefox will return false while Chrome and IE are behaving the way I'd expect and will return true using their respective transform prefix. If, however, I use the "in" operator, it works just fine.

```
object = document.getElementById('myThing');
console.log(object.style.hasOwnProperty('MozTransform') // False
console.log("MozTransform" in object.style); // True
```

I was wondering if anyone could explain why hasOwnProperty is working so differently in Firefox.

Comment: jquery doc's address this issue [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2) This link [here](http://www.easyjquery.com/jquery-parsing-raw-html-and-hasownproperty-on-firefox/) offers some suggestions for getting around the issue when trying to find elements based on `.hasOwnProperty` , but it seems you already have a good solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per spec, properties like this are own properties of the prototype, not of the object itself.  Hence the behavior you see in Firefox.